# How to make git assembler forget a branch mid rebase?

Tags: git

I tried to use https://www.thregr.org/wavexx/software/git-assembler/ and one branch is not working well for rebasing. I removed it from .git/assembler but when I re-ran `git as -a -v` it still wanted to work on it. I am not sure where it keeps the current state or what commands are available to make it just forget a branch.